# Receiving an Error with VBA-Web HttpGet Call in MS Access

Tags: json, ms-access, vba

Web Library to process JSON calls in VBA:

https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web

This is the call in Postman which works fine:

```
curl -X GET \
  https://<URL>/ \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: dee67429-d5f8-45fd-8004-f5c244729526' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d 'api_key=<Key>'
```

I'm struggling in Access to get the VBA-Web code to work. This is what I've coded:

```
Dim Client As New WebClient
Dim Request As New WebRequest
Dim Response As WebResponse
Dim Body As New Dictionary

Client.BaseUrl = "https:<URL>"

Request.Method = WebMethod.HttpGet
Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Request.AddBodyParameter "api_key", "<Key>"

Set Response = Client.Execute(Request)
```

It seems to be hitting the API as the Response in Content is, "{"error":"Invalid request"}". Any thoughts where I'm going astray? Please note, for this call there is no Request.Resource needed as it's at the root level. They have other APIs that are at the next level down.

Thanks!!!

Comment: What library are you getting `WebClient`, `WebRequest`, `WebResponse` and `WebMethod` from?

Comment: It doesn't look like you ever replace `<URL>` with the actual URL. Does this get set somewhere else in your code?